# What's the relationship between a React component and ReactElement?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, virtual-dom

I was reading a [section of the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-returned-from-reactdom.render) which uses the following vocabulary, but I can't figure out the relationship between them:

- A component
- A component's instance
- A component's backing instance
- A virtual DOM element
- A `ReactElement`

If and how are they related?

Comment: some of the concepts are explained [here](https://medium.com/@fay_jai/react-elements-vs-react-components-vs-component-backing-instances-14d42729f62#.5ulakfekn)

Comment: Thanks @eenagy for the article, it does help explain a lot of the concepts. From the article, it seems like the (normal) DOM is a tree containing HTML elements, and React's version of the Virtual DOM is a tree containing React Elements.

Comment: But I think the article is wrong in regards to backing instance. It says "`ReactDOM.render()` returns a React Component instance", but from the docs it says "`ReactDOM.render()` returns a *reference* to your component's *backing instance*" This [comment](https://medium.com/@lewis19921006/a-react-components-backing-instance-is-the-object-in-memory-that-represents-the-node-in-the-view-c4b4b339e3fe#.tekq38wcu) following the article also points this inconsistency out.

Answer (score 1):

**A virtual dom elements** are javascript objects which represents your DOM nodes for better rerendering/diffing/creation support instead updating your DOM at every state change.

**ReactElement** is a simple javascript object representing *visual pieces of your UI*. Which can be html element or other react component.
This javascript object will be associated with one or more virtual DOM element(s). This is for the sake of performance.

**Component**

According to docs it is

> specification object that contains a render method

Which I would add :

> for creating , combining and wrapping ReactElements with behaviour.

The behaviours can be the followings :

- *bind* data
- functions can be *bound* to DOM events
- extension/inheritance support for the components
- react's lifecycle support
- javascript flow control (hiding/ showing multiple components)

**Component's instance** plainly can be thought of as the same as object definition and object's instance.

Definition is a blueprint for creating the defined object(s).

For example if you have a List with multiple ListElement.

- *List*: holding grocery elements

  - *ListItem* : honey
  - *ListItem* : milk
  - *ListItem* : cereal
  - *ListItem* : fruits

One List definition **-->** one instance.

One ListElement definition **-->** multiple instances of that component

**Component's backing instance(s)** is/are the actually rendered element.

**Note**: when I say bind/bound I meant in the unidirectional sense.